# Two Instances of Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, include, simple-html-dom

I am currently using php include to source two files onto a web page.

The two different files say 1.php and 2.php have two different instances using simplehtmldom.

The issue is with 2.php when included onto the web page, shows the following error in its position.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_get_html() (previously declared in /home/northsho/public_html/w/pages/simple_html_dom.php:70) in /home/northsho/public_html/w/pages/simple_html_dom.php on line 85

**edit:**

further clarification.

master.php (includes 1.php and 2.php)

1.php and 2.php both use simple_html_dom.php

Comment: just for clarification, you have a master.php where you include 1.php and 2.php. And in both 1.php and 2.php you have `include "simple_html_dom.php"` ?

Comment: Yes this is the case, sorry I will make that more clear now

Comment: in this case, use `include "simple_html_dom.php"` in your master file. and in 1.php and 2.php just create the objects. make sure to unset and destroy at the end since simple html dom has some memory leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this structure, although you could do without including those 2 files and moving the contents into a function and passing the URL as a parameter

master.php

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

include '1.php';
include '2.php';
```

1.php

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('http://example.domain.com');

//do your job

//destroy the object at the end
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

2.php

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('http://anotherexample.domain.com');

//do your job

//destroy the object at the end
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

master.php using a function instead of including 2 other files

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

function doMyJob($url){
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    //do the actual job
    $result = $html->plaintext;

    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $result;
}

//call the function
print doMyJob("http://example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# FileA: simple_html_dom.php

if(!class_exists('simple_html_dom')){
    class simple_html_dom{
        // ...
    }
}

# FileB:include/require 'prefix_path/'.'simple_html_dom.php'
```

Comment: **Do** not use **require_once**, It's Inefficient